# No parameterless constructor defined for this object - working on local machine but not on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I see a lot of questions asking same question that I do but the weired thing is this works on my local which is windows 7 and IISExpress of VS 2013 but on production server it gives me this error. server has windows server 2008 and IIS 7.5 and dot net framework 4.5.1 (the app is asp.net mvc 4)

**stacktrace**

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Website.Web.Controllers.MainController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +86
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12638163
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

**MainController**

```
 public class MainController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork2 _uow2;
        private readonly IContract _contract;

        public MainController(IUnitOfWork2 uow2, IContract contract)
        {
            _contract = contract;
            _uow2 = uow2;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

and **BaseController**

```
 [Authorize]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User
        {
            get { return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal; }
        }
```

I have no idea why it's working on local but after publish gives me error !!

Comment: Looking at your controller constructor you are using some form of Dependency Injection. What package are you using to do that, and where are you doing that (usually the Global.asax)? It seems to me that in development your controller factory is (at run-time) replaced by the DI version, and after publish your controller factory is the original default controller factory from MVC (by looking at your stacktrace). Is your global.asax correctly published?

Comment: I used `StructuremapMvc` (an old version) and its in `App.App_Start`. nothing to do with Global.asax I guess

Comment: Ah you are probably using `WebActivator`. Maybe you can verify that the `Start` method actually runs, for example, logging the execution somewhere. Is the `WebActivator` assembly correctly published as well? Also maybe upgrade to the latest version of StructureMap?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old and likely resolved, but I thought I'd add my experience with this error. I have a project that started with MVC3 and I've recently upgraded it to MVC5 along with upgrading all packages associated. I am using Ninject for DI, so of course I upgraded that.  During that upgrade NuGet tells you it's going to copy over NinjectWebCommon.cs which holds your bindings.  So I let it copy over the file, then compared it with the previous version and copied the binding info in RegisterServices().  After that I could debug the software on my Win8 desktop and it ran perfectly, but after publishing with "Remove additional files at destination" checked I got the "No parameterless constructor defined" error.

Anyway, I decided to mess with Ninject since I figured that was the issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled it and forgot to reinstate the bindings from the previous version and ran it. I got the error while debugging this time and quickly realized where the problem was.  Somehow the blank copy of NinjectWebCommon.cs was getting to the server, not the one I updated with my bindings.

**tl;dr**

At least for me, the error comes from missing bindings in NinjectWebCommon.cs (or wherever your DI bindings are located) even though I DID copy them over to the newly replaced file.  So I guess, make sure those changes are getting to the server.